# Request permission with suggestion chips

Tags: user-interface, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm able to request permission for access to the user's name and precise location. Since this generates a question that can be answered yes or no, it would seem to be an ideal situation to display suggestion chips allowing a person to tap to agree instead of acknowledging out loud.

However, the following JSON doesn't seem to work. It continues to prompt for permission, but doesn't display the chips.

```
{
  "speech": "PLACEHOLDER_FOR_PERMISSION",
  "contextOut": [],
  "data": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "isSsml": false,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "PLACEHOLDER_FOR_PERMISSION"
            }
          }
        ],
        "suggestions": [
          {"title":"yes"},
          {"title":"no"}
        ]
      },
      "noInputPrompts": [],
      "systemIntent": {
        "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
        "data": {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
          "optContext": "To raise you up",
          "permissions": [
            "NAME",
            "DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to get the suggestion chips? Any better way to handle this?

Comment: I see this is using data.google which I think is v1 of the API.    I also think v2 uses payload.google.   Can you post your v2 of this json?

Comment: Have Google implemented this feature yet? I'd really like to be able to use it for location permission but the docs still don't reference it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there is not way to handle suggestion chips (per your example) BUT we are working on it and I hope that in a month we will have this ability.

Thank you for bring up this important use case.

Comment: Is this implemented? I am still not able to use suggestion chips with permissions.